# expected primary-expression before 'int'- How can I sort out the problem?

Tags: c++, database, oop

I'm creating a database for Customer in C++. The firt void works well but the second one returns me the following error: ***expected primary-expression before 'int'***
Where is teh mistake? How can I figure out it?
I can't understand why I receive this error. I'm a beginner and this is my firt important project.
Many thanks!!!

```
                            #include <iostream>
                            #include <string>
                            #include <cstdlib>
                            #include <cstring>
                            #include <fstream>
                            #include <cstdio>

                            using namespace std;

                            class DataCustomer{    //initialize a class

                            public:
                                DataCustomer(){
                                    count = 0 ;
                                }


                                void AddCustomer();
                                void DisplayAll(int i);
                                void DeleteFile();
                                void EditFile();
                                void quit();
                                void search();
                                void searchName();
                                void searchSurname();
                                void searchCell();
                                void searchEmail();

                                int Menu();

                                //defining New Customer's details

                                struct NewCustomer
                                {
                                    char Name[20];
                                    char Surname[20];
                                    char Birthday[10];
                                    char PhoneNum [15];
                                    char Email[20];
                                };

                                NewCustomer entries [10000];
                                int count;
                            };

                            void DataCustomer::AddCustomer()
                            {
                                cout<<"Enter a Name: ";
                                ofstream a_file ("database.txt", ios::app);
                                cin >> entries[count].Name;
                                a_file << entries [count].Name<<"\n";
                                cin.clear();
                                cin.sync();
                                cout << "Enter a Surname: ";
                                cin >> entries[count].Surname;
                                a_file << entries[count].Surname << "\n";
                                cin.clear();
                                cin.sync();
                                cout << "Enter Date of Birth: ";
                                cin >> entries[count].Birthday;
                                a_file << entries[count].Birthday << "\n";
                                cin.clear();
                                cin.sync();
                                cout << "Enter Phone Number: ";
                                cin >> entries[count].PhoneNum;
                                a_file << entries[count].PhoneNum << "\n";
                                cin.clear();
                                cin.sync();
                                cout << "Enter Email: ";
                                cin >> entries[count].Email;
                                a_file << entries[count].Email << "\n";
                                a_file.close();

                               ++count;
                            }

                            void DataCustomer::DisplayAll(int i)
                            {
                                    system ("cls");
                                    cout<<"Entire Customers' database:"<<endl;
                                    ifstream a_file ( "database.txt" );

                                    a_file>> entries[i].Name;
                                    a_file>> entries[i].Surname;
                                    a_file>> entries[i].Birthday;
                                    a_file>> entries[i].PhoneNum;
                                    a_file>> entries[i].Email;
                                    cout << "Name : " << entries[i].Name << endl;
                                    cout << "Surname: " << entries[i].Surname << endl;
                                    cout << "Date of birth : " << entries[i].Birthday << endl;
                                    cout << "Phone number : " << entries[i].PhoneNum << endl;
                                    cout << "Email: " << entries[i].Email << endl;

                                    cout << "Number of Entries : " << count << endl;

                               for(int i = 0;i < count;++i)
                                  {cout << endl;
                                  DisplayAll(i); }
                            }

                            DataCustomer db;

                            int main ()
                            {
                                db.DisplayAll(int i);
                                return 0;
                            }
```

Comment: What is `db.DisplayAll(int i);` supposed to do? That's no C++.

Comment: I want to display all Customer.  It's dot. operator

Comment: Wow, there are too many spaces in the left of your code!

Comment: ahhahah...I want to be fast when I paste the code in stackoverflow box

Comment: Your `void DataCustomer::DisplayAll(int i)` will fail into an infinite recursion when `count` is positive.

Comment: how can I change the code? As I told you, I'm a beginner.

Comment: Hint: In `DisplayAll` you call `DisplayAll(i);` - that's syntactically right, allthough it doesn't make much sense in this location. In `main` you have `db.DisplayAll(int i);` - spot the difference.

Comment: if I change "int i" with "i" in main I receive that "i" was not declared for this scope

Comment: It is because `i` is not declared there. Change that to what you want. `0` is one candidate of that.

Comment: You should descrive the desired behavior of your code.

Comment: many thanks!!!! Merry Christmas

Comment: "how can I change the code?" Click the grey word [edit] beneath your post (or the blue version here). It then becomes obvious

Comment: "many thanks!!!!" If you founf a solution please create an answer (and you can accept it) or ask the correspondung commenter to create one and accept that.